# Before set or get a property, a method should executed, which is not known at compile time?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

Before set or get a property, a method should executed, which is not known at compile time?
Is it possible to add methodes as runtime?

```
public string MyName 
{
    get 
    { 
        //A Methode should called here
        return m_ASD; 
    }
    set 
    { 
        //A Methode should called here
        m_ASD = value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What is exactly your goal?

Comment: It can be dangerous though. If the called method will set / get the `MyName` Property, then it will cause an infinite loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest solution would be to provide hooks that can be set at runtime:

```
public Action OnMyNameSet { get; set; }
public Action OnMyNameGet { get; set; }
public string MyName
{
    get
    {
        if (OnMyNameGet != null) { OnMyNameGet(); }
        return m_ASD;
    }
    set
    {
        if (OnMyNameSet != null) { OnMyNameSet(); }
        m_ASD = value;
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.OnMyNameSet = NameOfSomeMethod;
c.MyName = ...;                   // also executes NameOfSomeMethod();
```

---

Alternatively, you can create *events* that the consumer can attach to. This is how hooks are usually implemented in the .NET framework.

```
public event EventHandler OnMyNameSet;
public event EventHandler OnMyNameGet;
public string MyName
{
    get
    {
        if (OnMyNameGet != null) { OnMyNameGet(this, EventArgs.Empty); }
        return m_ASD;
    }
    set
    {
        if (OnMyNameSet != null) { OnMyNameSet(this, EventArgs.Empty); }
        m_ASD = value;
    }
}
```

The usage is similar; note, however, the use of `+=` instead of `=`:

```
MyClass c = new MyClass();
c.OnMyNameSet += NameOfSomeMethod;
c.MyName = ...;                   // also executes NameOfSomeMethod(sender, eventArgs);
```

Comment: You can do this with a delegate chain as well - expose methods to add/remove methods to a delegate object, then invoke the delegate object in the property. The advantage is that you can then implicitly invoke multiple methods (as many as are in the chain) and you avoid the null test (invoking an empty chain has no effect).

Comment: @Eight-BitGuru: True. I've added an alternative with an event instead of an Action, which has similar advantages (multiple methods) and is more idiomatic to .NET than a delegate chain (although, under the hood, events are implemented using delegate chains).

Comment: @Heinzi thanks! (I have a solution with calls a Methode from the Base class) Are any solution without changing the MyName property also possible ?

Comment: @RaphaelRi: Unfortunately, this is not possible, as far as I know.